# For the calculation of $\sum_{x \in \mathcal{Z}}\sum_{x \in \mathcal{X}}P(Z=z,X=x)$, would it matter if $X, Z$ were independent?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

If we have $X$ is a discrete random variable, then we can rewrite it using marginalization as:

$$
P(Z) = \sum_{x \in \mathcal{X}}P(Z,X=x)
$$

My question is, suppose that $Z$ and $X$ are independent. Would we then have:

\begin{align}
P(Z) &= \sum_{x \in \mathcal{X}}P(Z,X=x) \\
&= \sum_{x \in \mathcal{X}}P(Z)P(X=x)\\
&= P(Z) \sum_{x \in \mathcal{X}}P(X=x) \\
&= P(Z)
\end{align}

Hence, does marginalization not care about the independence structure between my random variables?

As another example, would it matter if $X$ and $Y$ were independent here at all:

$$
\sum_{x \in \mathcal{Z}}\sum_{x \in \mathcal{X}}P(Z=z,X=x)
$$
?
If they were, it seem that

$$
\sum_{x \in \mathcal{Z}}\sum_{x \in \mathcal{X}}P(Z=z)P(X=x) = \sum_{x \in \mathcal{Z}}P(Z=z)\sum_{x \in \mathcal{X}}P(X=x) = 1\cdot 1 = 1
$$

Wouldnt this be the same as before?

Answer (score 0):

The first fact, law of total probability, follows from the fact that if $A$ is an event in the sample space $S$, and $B_1, B_2, \ldots, B_n$ (can be countably infinite) forms a partition over $S$, i.e. they are collectively exhaustive $\displaystyle \bigcup_{i=1}^n B_i = S$ and mutually exclusive $B_i \cap B_j = \varnothing, \forall i\neq j$, then

$$ A = A \cap S = A \cap \bigcup_{i=1}^n B_i = \bigcup_{i=1}^n (A \cap B_i)$$

So the result is independent of the choice of probability measure. Here whether $A$ and $B_i$ are independent or not is irrelevant - they are independent or not depends on which probability measure you are with respect to.

The second one I assume you are summing $z$ in the outer sum:

$$ \sum_{z\in\mathcal{Z}} \sum_{x\in\mathcal{X}}\Pr\{Z = z, X = x\} = \sum_{z\in\mathcal{Z}} \Pr\{Z = z\} = 1$$

by noting that summing the joint pmf over all support points will yields the (joint) pmf of the remaining variables, with one less dimension. It has nothing to do with the independence - you do not need it.